# Using a wifi adapter with the raspberry pi

Tags: wifi

a friend of mine recently got me a wifi adapter to use with my raspberry pi, unfortunately, the driver comes in the form of a CD. Does anyone know whether I can get around this somehow? Can I get a driver for it and put it in the SD card used to load up the OS? Using my ethernet cord has become a bit of a drag. Thanks guys!

Comment: Copy the files to a flash drive. Are you sure it needs a driver (that isn't already installed/available)? What happens if you just plug it in. is it listed in dmesg output or in lsusb output? It would help if we new the make and ideally the chipset used by the WiFi dongle.

Comment: I would throw the CD away and look for an exisiting driver that's already in the kernel. The CD is unlikely to contain a Linux driver. If it did, it would likely be either a binary blob compiled for an x86 arch or sources for a driver that's meant to be compiled against an outdated kernel version.

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not need to do that, particularly since that CD is very unlikely to contain linux driver source code, which is what you would need to use it on the pi (I'm presuming you are using Raspbian or something similar).  That, or linux versions that have been compiled for the ARM architecture used on the pi, which is even less likely (because normal computers don't use it) and generally useless anyway (because such drivers have to be compiled for particular kernel versions, which is not worthwhile bothering with on the pi).

First, **without** the adapter attached, *after a fresh reboot*:

```
cd ~
lsmod > lsmod1.txt
lsusb > lsusb1.txt
```

The last command may not exist and you will first have to `apt-get install usbutils`.  You probably won't see much or any output at this point.  It is being written to those (small) files.  You can look at them afterward with `cat` or `less` or whatever you like but you don't have to at this point.

Now stick in the adapter.  On older models (A/B), this may cause the pi to reboot -- wifi adapters are often things that must be plugged in first and cannot be reattached once removed.  This is due to a design flaw.  In any case, now do the same thing with slightly different filenames.

```
cd ~
lsmod > lsmod2.txt
lsusb > lsusb2.txt
```

And:

```
diff lsmod1.txt lsmod2.txt
diff lsusb1.txt lsmod2.txt
```

Any differences you see there will probably be due to the wifi adapter (if the pi rebooted, that's a complication, but it could still likely be true).  If the first one in particular shows stuff, you are probably in luck, because it means the kernel includes drivers that should work with that adapter.  Next:

```
ip link | grep wlan0
```

If you see something, then it is all working -- or most likely so -- and you have a wifi interface.